# How to debug stored procedure on Microsoft SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2017

I need to debug stored procedure on the local SQL Server using data stored in this server.

I have on my device:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.0 Preview 5
- Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Debugger was removed from SSMS 17.9 and newer.

**Attempt 1**. Debug usign SSMS 2014. I got following error messages:

[image]

> Unable to start program 'MSSQL:://localhost/MyDB/sys/=0'.

Same error for stored procedures that have no parameters.

**Attempt 2**. Debug using Visual Studio.

I can execute stored procedures and even change them on the SQL server side via VS.

But similar errors when I try to debug:

> Failed to start debugger. An exception was generated: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'
>
> Unable to start program 'MSSQL:://localhost/?/sys/=0'. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005.

So how am I supposed to debug stored procedures in Microsoft SQL Server 2017?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is your ssms service turned on; on this localhost of yours.

Comment: It sounds like debugging is gone from new SSMS.. if you can’t find an older version may be it’s time to switch to another IDE https://sqlserver.miraheze.org/wiki/The_Ideal_IDE

Comment: @junketsu what do you mean by ssms service? Can't find anything similar in my services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to go all the way back to SSMS 2014.  SSMS 17.8.1 is still available for [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-ssms-releases).

Or you can use [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) in Visual Studio to debug.

[How to: Debug Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: "Debug Procedure...." and "Execute with Debugger" does **not appear** in my SSMS (V18.3.1). Also, I cannot set break points. What can I do to enable it?

Comment: I am currently evaluating the option specified [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221349/how-to-add-the-debug-button-to-ssms-v18)